# Entityframework DbContext returns old data in Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, forms, entity-framework

I am using [Generic Repository Patter](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle)n in my Windows Form application. I am facing issue while updating and fetching records.

I have created a Parent Form and Child Form with own DbContext object. I am updating some records in child form and then tried to get updated record in parent form, but Parent Form Context returns old data.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly AppContext _db;
    private readonly JobRepository _jobRepository;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _db = new AppContext();
        _jobRepository = new JobRepository(_db);

    }

  // Calling _jobRepository.getAll();
}
```

Child Form Code:

```
public partial class JobOptionsForm : Form
{
    private readonly AppContext _db;
    private readonly JobRepository _jobRepository;


    public JobOptionsForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _db = new AppContext();          
        _jobRepository = new JobRepository(_db);
    }

    public btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        _jobRepository.UpdateData(..);
       // Close form and returns to parent form
    }

}
```

Child Form returns updated records. Should I need to make a single Dbcontext Instance for whole application?

Comment: You should not reuse DbContext at all. Create context, do what you need, dispose context. In your case - get records, update records, dispose context. When refreshing form (to get new objects) - create new context.

Comment: So every time I need to dispose the objects and again instantiate the DbContext? Do you think any performance issue with this act?

Comment: For your scenario there is none. Even connection is not usually closed immediatly when you dispose your context, but is instead put to the pool. Anyway, potential performance impact of doing this in your scenario is almost zero. Entity Framework context follows so called "unit of work" pattern, so you should try to use it accordingly.

Comment: So I tell that because the problem you encounter related to this: when you make a query which returns some entities, context remembers those entities so that you might later change them and save those changes. In some cases, if entity is already remembered by the context, it might be returned for your query (such as Find) instead of doing database query. It also happens when you access navigation property - if entity related to that navigation property is already known to the context - it will return it instead. To not worry about such things - try to use one context for one operation only.